# How easily to connect to sensorTag device using swift in iOS

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, iot, texas-instruments, ibmwearables

I have a sensorTag device and I want to start using it without implementing the bluetooth connectivity layer, what is the easiest way to use it in swift?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to connect to sensorTag (and other devices) in swift is to use
the IBM Mobile Wearables SDK

you can read about it here:
http://wearables.mybluemix.net/

and get it for free here:
https://github.com/ibm-wearables-sdk-for-mobile/ibm-wearables-swift-sdk